# Export data from Active Directory LDAP to AWS S3

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, amazon-s3, ldap

I need to export data from AD LDAP (about 11 millions entities) as JSON to AWS S3.

I used with LdapTemplate and export it parallel (thread for each ObjectClass).

This is take too long; I use with `PagedResultsDirContextProcessor` (page of 1000-20000 without change in time manner)

Any idea how can I make it faster? maybe give the LdapTemplate some kind of ExecutorService that can run it faster?

Thanks!